# Serialize Object from a war deploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was getting into trouble when tried to find a solution for my  problem. 
I have an xml Schema that I download from the internet and create SchemaFactory with it.
The code goes like this:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

The problem is that it takes a descent amount of time to load it so I want to serialize this object and then deserialize it .
I didn't succeed to even create a file within a war(read file I found how to do).
Would be glad if someone could help me.
Thanks,
Pavel

Comment: Writing serialized object(data) to the *.war(application) is a bad idea. Its better to use the work area of the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a new file dynamically in a running war. You may use an external directory to store the serialized object in a file, though, or store it in a database.

Comment: My intention was to use the work area of the webapp.
But how do I get the path dynamically ? I don't know where it will be stored and unpacked yet.

Comment: A webapp doesn't necessarily have a work area. The app server classloader could keep everything packed into the war file. The container must provide you a temporary directory where you can store what you want, though. Get it using servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR)

Comment: @Pavel: Can't you cache the SchemaFactory in memory - `servletContext.setAttribute(...);`?